# Routable componet of Razor Class Library not displayed in ASP.NET Core 6.0 WebAssembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor, webassembly

I have an ASP.NET Core 6.0 WebAssembly in which I have included a Razor class library. The library contains several components, including three that use the `@page` directive. After a login (implemented with IdentityServer4) it is directed to one of the routable components from the library. The problem: the component is not displayed...

I checked the following:

- The library is referenced by the WebAssembly
- In `App.razor` I added `AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Helper).Assembly, typeof(Confirmation).Assembly, typeof(HelperRegistration).Assembly }"`.

I found the following:

- No errors are displayed in either the Visual Studio output or the browser DevTools console.
- Nothing is noticeable in the Network tab of Browser DevTools.
- `protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()` of the routable component is called.

I tried this:

- Call the `StateHasChanged()` method of the layout component from the `OnInitializedAsync()` method. The idea behind it was that
  Trigger rendering of the component from the library.

The components in the Razor class library were previously implemented directly in the Blazor WebAssembly and that's how it all worked! My goal is to integrate the library later with lazy load.

Comment: Try to set the `RedirectUri` request parameter to the url of the routable component.

Comment: "..... were previously implemented directly in the Blazor ...". You did thoroughly delete them right?  Because I see no namespaces in your AdditionalAssemblies.

Comment: Smoke test: put `<Helper />`  on an empty local page..

Comment: @enet I think you are talking about `RedirectUri` in IdentityServer4. I have several roles in my WebAssembly, each with different masks and other routable components. I therefore have the forwarding in Index.razor. But thanks to your hint, I have now seen in a quick search that it is apparently also possible to specify multiple Uris in identity server. So that would be another try. Thank you!

Comment: @HenkHolterman The empty local page loads but `<Helper />` doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. It wasn't the display of components, it was the way I integrated the navigation menu. This was not displayed as I expected, but it was correct that no component was displayed at that moment.

The hints helped me to find the cause of my error. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to test your library pages like this:

1. Set one of your library pages with a `@page "/"`
2. Set `App` `AppAssembly`to point to a class library. Here's an example below.

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Blazor.App.UI.App).Assembly">
...
```

What happens.  Does the library route load as the default route?

#### Additional Information based on Response

I have this in one of my test solutions, which works.  Note I use fully qualified namespace names.  `Blazor.App.UI.Index` is the index page which is in the `Blazor.App.UI` assembly/namespace.  I also like to keep my Razor very clean, which is why the list is defined in the @code block.

```
@namespace Blazor.App.UI
@using System.Reflection

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Blazor.App.Core.ListOptions).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="@Assemblies">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code {
    private List<Assembly> Assemblies => new List<Assembly>() { typeof(Blazor.App.UI.Index).Assembly  };
}
```

In your line:

```
AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Helper).Assembly, typeof(Confirmation).Assembly, typeof(HelperRegistration).Assembly }"
```

Are `Helper`, `Configuration` and `HelperRegistration` in the same assembly?  If so then you should only reference the assembly once.

Comment: Yes the library routes as the default route.

Comment: @user18153346 . See the additions to my answer.